# Limit Derivative of solution to linear complementarity problem at discontinuity

Tags: derivatives, linear-programming, piecewise-continuity, non-smooth-analysis

Consider the linear complementarity problem with $\mathbf{M}$ a $P$-matrix and a vector $\mathbf{q}$ with unknown $\mathbf{z}$:

Find $\mathbf{z}$ such that $\mathbf{M}\mathbf{z}+\mathbf{q} \geq \mathbf{0}, \mathbf{z} \geq \mathbf{0}, \mathbf{z}^\top (\mathbf{M}\mathbf{z}+\mathbf{q})  = \mathbf{0}$.

Let's call the solution to this LCP $\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{LC}(\mathbf{M},\mathbf{q})$. Given that $\mathbf{M}$ is a $P$-matrix, we know that $\mathbf{z}$ exists for any $\mathbf{q}$.

Now, consider a vector function $\mathbf{q}(t)$ that has a continuous derivative $\dot{\mathbf{q}}(t)$ and $\mathbf{z}(t) = \mathbf{LC}(\mathbf{M},\mathbf{q}(t))$. Assume there exist an instant $t_0$ where, for some $i$, we have:
\begin{equation}
z_i(t_0) = \lambda_i(t_0)  = 0
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\lambda_i(t_0) = q_i(t_0) + \sum\limits_{j} M_{ij}z_j(t_0)
\end{equation}

**Problem:**
Define the derivative $\dot{\mathbf{z}}(t_0^+)$.

My procedure:

1. $\dot{\mathbf{z}}(t_0^+)$ exists since $\mathbf{z}(t) = \mathbf{LC}(\mathbf{M},\mathbf{q}(t))$ exists everywhere and is piecewise-linear and continuous.
2. $t_0$ marks a point of discontinuity in $\dot{\mathbf{z}}(t)$, i.e. we expect $z_i(t_0)$ to switch between satisfying $z(t) = 0, \lambda(t) > 0$ and $z(t) > 0, \lambda(t) = 0$
3. We know that the elements of $\mathbf{z}(t_0)$ can be in one of three states
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   z_i(t_0) = 0 & \lambda_i(t_0) > 0, \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{I}_1\\
   \lambda_i(t_0) = 0  & z_i(t_0) > 0, \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{I}_2  \\
   \lambda_i(t_0) = 0  & z_i(t_0) = 0, \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{I}_3  \\
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
   where the problem requires  $\mathcal{I}_3 \neq \emptyset$. Also, the union of $\mathcal{I}_1$, $\mathcal{I}_2$, $\mathcal{I}_3$ forms the complete set of all indices in $\mathbf{z}(t)$. Via differentiation of the above w.r.t $t$, we get
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   \dot{z}_i(t_0^+) = 0 & \lambda_i(t_0^+) > 0, \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{I}_1\\
   \dot{\lambda}_i(t_0^+) = 0  & z_i(t_0^+) > 0, \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{I}_2  \\
   \dot{\lambda}_i(t_0^+) = 0  & \text{ and/or } \dot{z}_i(t_0^+) = 0, \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{I}_3  \\
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
   The issue is with the last condition. However, since I know that we are at the moment of switch and both $\lambda_i(t_0^+) \leq 0$ and $z_i(t_0^+) \leq 0$ must be satisfied, I can say confidently
   \begin{equation}
   \dot{\lambda}_i(t_0^+) \geq 0 , \dot{z}_i(t_0^+) \geq 0, \dot{z}_i(t_0^+)\dot{\lambda}_i(t_0^+) = 0, \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{I}_3 
   \end{equation}
   which results in a new LCP problem (by plugging the necessary values in $\lambda_i(t_0^+)$) now acting on the derivative of the elements $i \in \mathcal{I}_3$.

Here I am at a bit of a loss:

A. Can I guarantee that the LCP resulting in 3 has a solution? the matrix of the LCP is indeed formulated from the minors of $\mathbf{M}$ but I am unsure if the matrix formed in 3 is a $P$-matrix as well.

B. I claim the following: since 1 is valid (!!!if it is!!!), the LCP formed in 3 leads to the formation of a problem with a unique solution and the matrix formed is therefore a $Q$-matrix.